# How to convert a JSON value to a JsonWebToken in eclipse microprofile

Tags: java, jwt, microprofile

I am extracting a `jwt token` from a `JSON` object in the following way.

```
enterpriseToken = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("enterpriseToken", jsonResult.getString("token")).build();
```

And now I want to get the subject from this token. But as per my understanding. to use `getSubject()` on my token, it should be `JsonWebToken` type. So I tried to convert my json value to `JsonWebToken` in this way.

```
JsonWebToken tempEntpToken = (JsonWebToken)jsonResult.get("token");
```

Once I compile and make a request, I am getting the following exception.

> has thrown exception unwinding now [INFO] class
>   org.glassfish.json.JsonStringImpl cannot be cast to class
>   org.eclipse.microprofile.jwt.JsonWebToken
>   (org.glassfish.json.JsonStringImpl is in unnamed module of loader
>   org.eclipse.osgi.int ernal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @226bfe63;